# my project search into App_Data folder for .mdf file , web.config settings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on MVC Project. (Right now I am using the SQL server ,local DB)

My project built with MVC project and data layer project. (Class Library)

The controllers have to get / pass the data from/To DataLayer from/To Views(MVC).

I am facing the problems with Web.Config and App.Config.

While running the project I get the following error.

I was confused abt why it looking for App_Data folder ?

```
{"The underlying provider failed on Open."}
{"Cannot attach the file 'D:\\BackUp\\5 may 2014\\MyDBname\\App_Data\\MyDBname.mdf' as database 'MyDBname'."}
```

here is the code of my web.config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MyDBname;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and here is my code of app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>

        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=MyDBname;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a connection string like this instead:

"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DatabaseName.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True

Comment: where ? in web.config or in App.config ?

Comment: put it in the Web.config

Comment: No, Its still looking for Add_Data folder